# Getting different offset top on first click then same in rest clicks

Tags: html, jquery, web, height, offset

[in image 1st is jquery(document).height() second is offset().top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6XkT.jpg)Trying to scroll to element with fix header but getting different value for offset().top on first click then getting the value i need from second click. I think then check the value of $(document).height() is also different for first click no idea what to to

Expecting same value for offset.top

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. If there is anything with lazy loading or loading after scroll remove it..